# 3Sum function debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, symbolic-math

I have been asked to fix this chunk of code. It is to do with sets and the 3Sum problem. I have used print statements and i am very close to the answer, but i get an IndexingError (list index out of range). Any help would be great

```
def count_c(A, B, C):

    """Counts the number of pairs a in A and b in B so that a + b == c

    nb. Assumes that A and B are sorted
    """
    rv = 0
    n = len(A)
    m = len(B)
    #t = len(C)
    AL, BL, CL = list(A), list(B), list(C)
    # i and j are "fingers" on A and B
    i, j = 0, m-1

    while i < n and j >= 0:

        for c in CL:
            a, b = AL[i], BL[j] #correct
            print ('a,b = ', (a,b))
            s = a + b #correct
            print('s = ', s)
            print ('i , j =', (i,j))

            if s == c:
                # found a pair that works
                rv = rv + 1 #correct
                # start again with a smaller b
                j = j - 1 #correct
            elif s > c:
                # too big. decrease the b contribution
                j = j - 1
            else:
                # means s < c, increase the a contribution
                i = i + 1

    return rv

def three_sum(A, B, C):
    """Solves 3SUM+"""

    return count_c(A,B,C)
```

IndexingError (list index out of range)

Comment: what index is wrong where? did you debug it? why is j starting at 0 and then only ever reduced and never increased? why is the loop running only if j is >= 0? what happens if j is smaller then the amount of values in your list? say: j = -6 and LB = [0,1,2,3,4]

Comment: Why not `def count_c(A, B, C): 
    return sum( a+b==C for a in A for b in B)` ? This is quadratic and not very effective but works. You do not really factor in sorting for early termination of your algo anyhow...

Comment: Your while loop and your for loop need to be inverted. Also, don't forget to reset i and j each time you enter the while loop. @PatrickArtner : Sorting of A and B does play a role here, to bring complexity down from O(|A|*|B|*|C|) to O((|A|+|B|)*|C|) (using a "sliding window" technique)

Comment: @Tassle - lol I know. What **I** ment: his solution does not _use_ this fact at all - so he could as well go for the O(n*m) approach (that works) unless it is a performance problem. Optimizing it down to O(n+m) (|C| is 1 anyhow) can be done after that.